# Javascript : event handler doesn't work in an select option (IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, event-handling, html-select

When I bind a event handler in an select option, the function called by this event handler doesn't work in Internet Explorer (works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari).

Here is the code, very simple :

```
<select onmousedown="display_options(this, 10);">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

function display_options(this_select, size)
{   

    /*If the select size is greater than size parameter, apply size parameter to the select :*/
    if(this_select.length > size)
    {
        this_select.size = size;

        /*Position absolute to simulate a classic select :*/
        this_select.style.position = "absolute";
    }

    /*When clicking in an option, come back to size 0 for the select. Works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but doesn't work in IE :*/
    for(var i = 0; i < this_select.options.length; i++)
    {           
            this_select.options[i].onclick = function(event)
            {
                this_select.size = 0;
            };          
    }

    /*When clicking outside the select, come back to size 0 for the select :*/
    this_select.onblur = function()
    {
        this_select.size = 0;
    };
}
```

In this code, this is the `this_select.options[i].onclick = function(event){...}` doesn't work in IE because the options list doesn't come back to size 0.

Have you an idea ? You can try the code : https://jsfiddle.net/4hck3vo0/

Thank you in advance, cordially.

Comment: Should be plenty of dupes on this, onclick does not work on options in IE. Use change on the select.

Comment: onchange in a select tag doesn't work if the option selected is the same than the previous selected option when the select size is greater than 1.

Comment: Than add click on the select

Comment: click instead of onmousedown on the select is worse, because it doesn't work in all browsers (the select size dont' comme back to 0).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that Internet Explorer is doing something quirky again. But why do you use onmousedown and onclick? If you don't have a specific reason for using them I'd suggest using the onChange attribute. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp for more info.

Comment: I don't use onchange, because onchange in a select tag doesn't execute the function if the option selected is the same than the previous selected option when the select size is greater than 1. I want the select come back to size 0 when you click the same option than the previous selected option.